# In Vista, how do I clean up the autorun "open with" menu when I plug my camera in?

Tags: windows-vista, autorun

When I plug my camera in, I've got Picasa 2 and two copies of Picasa 3 which come up (along with a bunch of other things).

Is there a way to clean this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**CleanHandlers** - AutoPlay cleanup utility](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/autoplayhandlers.htm) works for XP and Vista.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

gHacks has a comment referring this [Autoplay Repair](http://www-stud.uni-essen.de/~sddabacz/prog.php?id=apr) tool;
Found it while searching for a reference to [Clean Handlers](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/01/15/autoplay-cleanup-and-removal/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice little free tool called [Autoplay Repairer](http://www.vista4beginners.com/Add-custom-entries-to-Windows-Vista-AutoPlay) that should do what you require. You can customise every menu and basically do exactly what you want from a nice little GUI!

Comment: Is there a version of this for XP?